# iOS/Swift 3: Passing data backwards between non consecutive View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I know there are answers for passing data backwards, but they are for consecutive view controllers. I have 3 view controllers and a navigation controller. All segues are "show segue". I would like to pass data from VC3 to VC1. I'm trying to use delegate, but getting stuck:

```
    protocol Delegate:class {
        func getCityId(with id: String)
    }


    Class VC3:UIViewController{
     weak var delegate: Delegate?
    let id:String?

     func passDataBackwards() {

            delegate?.getCityId(with: self.id!)

    }

  }  
    Class VC1:UIViewController, Delegate{
     func getCityId(with id: String) {
            print ("id from search: \(id)")

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc3 = (segue.destination as! VC3)
          vc3.delegate = self
       }
   }
```

My problem is that I have 2 segues between my source and destination.
Your kind help will be appreciated.

Comment: An [unwind segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) is all you need

Comment: So it can't be done using delegate? My VC3 has a table view. Whenever I click on a cell, I want to move to VC1 and pass data to it. I'm not sure how I can do it with unwind.

Comment: You could use a delegate but it is messier. You need to define the protocol and pass the delegate "down the line" through view controllers that don't need it. By using an unwind method, VC1 can access the `sourceViewController` property of the storyboard segue passed its unwind method to get a reference to VC3. It can then read the required data from a property of vc3

Comment: Thank you, Paul. How can I connect a table view cell to the exit? @Paulw11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an unwind segue as shown in this [Apple Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html).

In your storyboard, create an Unwind segue as shown in the tech note and give it an identifier, say "unwindToVC1"

In VC3, create a property to store the selected value and use `performSegue` in your table's `didSelectRowAt` function to invoke it, having first stored the selected value in the property:

```
class VC3: UIViewController {

   var selectedValue: YourValueType?

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       self.selectedValue = myData[indexPath.row]
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToVC1", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Create an unwind action method in `VC1` and access the property

```
class VC1: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func unwind(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let sourceVC = sender.sourceViewController as? VC3 {
            if let selectedValue = sourceVC.selectedValue {
                // Do something with the selected value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can have any number of view controllers between the current VC and VC1 and get back to it with a simple unwind segue.

Comment: thank you for kindly answering. It looks like moving from VC3 to VC1 is done before self.selectedValue has a value, so it's always nil. When printing after each action, I see that func unwind(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) is called and only then I see a value for self.selectedValue from tableView function. @Paulw11

Comment: Make sure you haven't linked the unwind segue directly from your tableview  row in the storyboard; it needs to be a programmatic segue, so you should drag from the view controller object to the exit icon.

Comment: I know I'm a pain in the *** and I appreciate your patience, but I think that that's what I did: I've created an @IBAction func, then dragged a table view cell to the exit. I chose then the action from the list. Then I gave it an identifier. Is that correct?

Comment: No, not from the table view cell to exit, from the orange view controller to exit; you need to create a segue that can be triggered programatically

Comment: I didn't know about this option till now. It works great. Paul, you're always kind and super professional. Your help is not taken for granted even though we're strangers, thank you. @Paulw11